# How to retrieve a session value from a generic handler, and use that value in IF statement of jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json.net, session-state

I want to retrieve a session value that is `Session["somename"]` from a generic handler and then use that value in jquery if condition.

I have looked at some of the questions that have been asked related to this question and I have not find an answer yet. The code displays nothing on #div1 meaning result.Value is null. I don't know maybe the session value was not retrieved.

```cs
public class ReadSession: IHttpHandler,
System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new {
            Key = context.Request["key"],
            Value = context.Session[context.Request["key"]]
        }));
    }
}
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ReadSession.ashx',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    key: 'Somename',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Value != null)
        {
            $('#div1').append('<li>' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

I expect jquery to display a message on #div1 if the Result.Value != null.

Comment: what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ReadSession.ashx',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    key: 'Somename',
    success: function (result) {
                  $('#div').append('<li><strong>' + result.Value + '</li>');
}
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

Comment: It displays null  on #div but not the value of the session.